# Normality assumption n=48

Tags: model-evaluation, normality-assumption, sample, vector-autoregression

Regarding normality assumptions for model evaluation I have been told by my supervisor that it is not needed in the case of analyzing but is needed in forecasting only. i am looking for an explanation.

Comment: Hello and welcome ! More detail is needed. Please edit your question and describe your study design, the data you intend to collect and your research question.

Comment: Also please describe your model (regression (and what kind)? Factor analysis? Time series?)   And also what you think the assumptions are.

Comment: i think you would be better off asking your supervisor what they meant

Answer (score 3):

From my understanding, more important than normally distributed variables (prior to modelling) is the normality of model residuals (evaluated from a Q-Q plot, for example) after your model has been fit. Is this relevant to your question? Here is a paper describing this misconception (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5436580/)

Also, more information on your problem would be helpful!